# Remove a hypen and word from uri in nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

The actual link structure is as follows:

domain.com/abc/xyz/lmn/1.0.0-alpha/abc.html
we want is to redirect to

domain.com/abc/xyz/lmn/1.0/abc.html

By using rewrite in nginx

How this can be done in nginx?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Im not sure what the other requirements are but if it is just a static url it should work.

```
location = domain.com/abc/xyz/lmn/1.0.0-alpha/abc.html {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ domain.com/abc/xyz/lmn/1.0/abc.html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of these, take a look at the [`map`](http://nginx.org/r/map) directive.

But in any case, my advice would be to generate a simple page telling the user that the version they're looking for is outdated, and a new one is available, instead of doing an automated redirect:

```
location /abc/zyz/lmn/1.0 {
    rewrite ^(/abc/zyz/lmn/1\.0)(?:\.0-alpha)(abc.html)$ $1$2 break;
    return 404
        "<!DOCTYPE html><title>404 Not Found: $request_uri</title>
         <h1>404 Not Found: $request_uri</h1>
         <h2>The version you're seeking is outdated.
         Try <a href='$uri'>$uri</a> instead.</h2>"
}
```